# jQuery value not updating in result for cordova mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am working in cordova application and tried to get value from server though `$.get();` and `jQuery.ajax();` but result is not updating. Everything is working perfect in Emulator but not in Device. I want to know why the values not going to update while value from server is changed. Is any way to solve this or can i delete all app data through code in cordova.

I already search online for solutions also change my code many times but still result is same.

My code :

```
function getdata(){
 /*$.get('http://example.com/appFiles/serverping.txt',false,function(data,status){
    log('data'+data);
    alert("data :"+data + status);
    if(data==1){ // value of "data" after installation if 0 then remain 0 till uninstall or delete data of application from application manager
        log('playing');
        playAudio();

    }
}); */
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/appFiles/serverping.txt',
    success: function(result){
        log('ajax result : '+result);
        if(result==1){   // same above problem here with result too.
            log('playing');
            playAudio();
        }else{
            log('getting 0 from server');
        }
    },
    async:false
});
}
```

App Result :

[image: app result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add time in the url as following :

```
url:'http://example.com/appFiles/serverping.txt?date='+ new Date().getTime(),
```

Comment: can you please explain me why it is like that.

Comment: Previously, the result value is taken from cache.But when you add time in the url the url is reloaded and updated value is taken.